# Using Regex.Replace with MatchEvaluator function in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following piece of code,

```
 private void ReplaceVariables(DynamicForm form, DynamicEmailTemplate emailTemplate, List<DynamicFieldValue> fieldValues)
 {
     Regex regex = new Regex("\\?([\\w-]+)\\?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     // Replace Form Display Title Variables
     MatchCollection formDisplayTitleRegexMatches = regex.Matches(form.FormDisplayTitle);

     if (formDisplayTitleRegexMatches.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach (Match formDisplayTitleRegexMatch in formDisplayTitleRegexMatches)
         {
             foreach (var fieldValue in fieldValues)
             {
                 var formformDisplayTitleRegexMatchRemovedQuestionMarks = formDisplayTitleRegexMatch.Groups[1].Value;

                 if (formformDisplayTitleRegexMatchRemovedQuestionMarks.Equals(fieldValue.FieldCode))
                 {
                     form.FormDisplayTitle = form.FormDisplayTitle.Replace(formDisplayTitleRegexMatch.Value, fieldValue.Value);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

```
IEnumerable<string> labelsInEmailTemplate = emailTemplate
  .Entries
  .Select(x => x.FormField.FieldDefinition.FieldLabel);

foreach (string labelInEmailTemplate in labelsInEmailTemplate)
{
    MatchCollection labelRegexMatches = regex.Matches(labelInEmailTemplate);

    if (labelRegexMatches.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Match labelRegexMatch in labelRegexMatches)
        {
            foreach (DynamicFieldValue fieldValue in fieldValues)
            {
                string labelRegexMatchRemovedQuestionMarks = labelRegexMatch.Groups[1].Value;

                if (labelRegexMatchRemovedQuestionMarks.Equals(fieldValue.FieldCode))
                {
                    DynamicEmailTemplateEntry emailTemplateEntryToUpdate = emailTemplate
                        .Entries
                        .Find(x => x
                            .FormField
                            .FieldDefinition
                            .FieldLabel
                            .Contains(labelRegexMatch.Value));

                    emailTemplateEntryToUpdate
                        .FormField
                        .FieldDefinition
                        .FieldLabel = emailTemplateEntryToUpdate
                             .FormField
                             .FieldDefinition
                             .FieldLabel
                             .Replace(labelRegexMatch.Value, WebUtility.HtmlEncode(fieldValue.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample title variable can be - `?MY_Title? and ?MyName?`

I have 2 foreach loops, instead, is it possible to use MatchEvaluator and a delegate passing to `Regex.Replace`?

Made another update, is it possible to use Replace when I have 2 foreach loops, as I cannot update the record through foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can try rewriting you code into `Regex.Replace`, something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\?[\w-]+\?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

form.FormDisplayTitle = regex.Replace(form.FormDisplayTitle, match => {
  // get rid of leading and trailing ?
  var name = match.Value.Trim('?');

  // check if match corresponds to any FieldCode
  foreach (var fieldValue in fieldValues) 
    if (name.Equals(fieldValue.FieldCode))
      return fieldValue.Value; // Code found, Value returned
  
  // Unknown FieldCode, do nothing (return match intact)
  return match.Value; 
});
```

Here for each `match` lambda function is called where we should return the substitution: either `fieldValue.Value` or match itself - `match.Value` - if value has not been found.

**Update:** The second fragment can be rewritten as follow:

```
// For each entry in emailTemplate.Entries
foreach (var DynamicEmailTemplateEntry entry in emailTemplate.Entries) {
  // given lable teemplate...
  string labelTemplate = entry
    .FormField
    .FieldDefinition
    .FieldLabel;

  // ... we compute actual label
  string updatedLabel = regex.Replace(labelTemplate, match => {
    var name => match.Value.Trim('?');
  
    // either FieldValue or match as it is
    return fieldValue
      .Where(fv => fv.FieldCode == name)
      .Select(fv => fv.Value)
      .FirstOrDefault(match.Value);
  });

  // which we assign to template 
  entry
    .FormField
    .FieldDefinition
    .FieldLabel = updatedLabel; 
}
```

Comment: Solution works great, thanks! I updated my question, with another method there are 2 foreach loops, and I cannot update the record in foreach as it is read-only. Is it possible to use Replace there?

Comment: @tRuEsAtM: The very same princile: for each `entry` within `Entries` we get template, replace placeholders with a help of regular expresssions; then we assign label back.